$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}}$ without L'Hospital
I had to compute the limit for $\frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.
I had no idea besides the sandwich theorem or L'Hopital.
My tutor suggested:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}}=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(1-2n^2)}\\ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\iff
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}} \cdot "-\infty"$$
and as the square term converges way faster than any square root term, it has to diverge.
I've got several problems with this rationale though. First of all, any square root term??? But $\sqrt{x^6}=x^3$ surely is not smaller than $x^2~\forall x>1$.
Also, the limit product rule is only defined when the limits of the functions exist but since $\pm \infty$ is the limit of $1-n^2$, it doesn't exist, right? He told me it has something to do with infinities and I think continuous functions is what he said so he persisted on this answer.
The reasoning from my side would be the following:
$$\frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+5n^4}}>   \frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}>   \frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4}}\\
~~~~~~~\frac{1-2n^2}{3n^2}>   \frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}>    \frac{1-2n^2}{2n^2}\\
~~~~~\frac{1}{3n^2}-\frac{2}{3}>  \frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}>   \frac{1}{2n^2}-1\\
$$
Thus the limit cannot diverge to $-\infty$, as it has to be between $-\frac{2}{3}$ and $-1$, right? It doesn't give me the limit really but at least it gives me some bounds and tells me that it shouldn't diverge.
As I cannot reach him for about 2 weeks now and he persisted on his answers, I'm highly confused right now.

What happens if you divide the numerator and denominator by $n^2$?

The limit is $-1$, not $-\infty$.

Wolfram indicates/suggests that the limit is -1, so your recollection of what your tutor said is suspect. (It could be that you misunderstood them.)

@Math101 What exactly do you mean by that? I divided sum terms of the numerator each by the denominator -> step 2 (so line 3) And in the limit as n approaches infinity, the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ terms converge to 0

@CalvinLin Yeah, I also looked it up on WolframAlpha and told him immediately but he told me that computer programs are not a proof as WolframAlpha. Also, I'm sure I didn't misunderstand them. At least not on the side of the reasoning with the polynomial against root. The last thing with the infinities and continuity, I'm in fact not so sure about.

My approach would be the following, let
$$a_n = \frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+n^3}}$$
We do a little algebra
$$a_n = \frac{n^2\bigg( \frac{1}{n^2}-2\bigg)}{\sqrt{n^4\big(4+\frac{1}{n}\big)}}= \frac{n^2\bigg( \frac{1}{n^2}-2\bigg)}{n^2\sqrt{\big(4+\frac{1}{n}\big)}} =\frac{\bigg( \frac{1}{n^2}-2\bigg)}{\sqrt{\big(4+\frac{1}{n}\big)}}$$
So we have our initial limit
$$\require{cancel}\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\bigg( {\cancelto{0}{\frac{1}{n^2}}}-2\bigg)}{\sqrt{\big(4+\cancelto{0}{\frac{1}{n}}\big)}} = \frac{-2}{2} = -1 $$

I looked at your boundaries and we get the same results in fact
$$a_n \leq \frac{1-2n^2}{2n^2} = \frac{1}{2n^2}-1$$
while $\forall \varepsilon>0$
$$a_n \geq \frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+\varepsilon n^4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4+\varepsilon}\ n^2}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{4+\varepsilon}}$$
and we got
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+\varepsilon}\ n^2}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{4+\varepsilon}} \leq a_n \leq \frac{1-2n^2}{2n^2} = \frac{1}{2n^2}-1$$
and as $n\to \infty,\varepsilon \to 0$ we squeeze
$$-1\leq a_n \leq -1$$
but still no divergence.

Ah yeah, that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

When the variable approaches $\infty$, and when the function only contains polynomials (including roots that are only rational powers...) the rule is to consider the highest level elements and divide everything by that. That way all other terms will approach $0$. Here:
$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}}&=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{-2n^2(1-\frac 1 {2n^2})}{2n^2\sqrt{1+\frac 1{2n}}}
= -\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1-\frac 1 {2n^2}}{\sqrt{1+\frac 1{2n}}}\\
&=-1
\end{aligned}$$

Simply write that
$$ \frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}} = \frac{n^2 \left( 1/n^2 - 2 
 \right)}{n^2\sqrt{4+2/n}}=\frac{1/n^2 - 2 }{\sqrt{4+2/n}} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow} \frac{-2}{\sqrt{4}}=-1$$

how is this different from the previous 2 answers?

Among the nice and effective methods already suggested, following your idea by squeeze theorem (no the best way but a possible way), we can proceed as follows using that
$$\frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4}}\le \frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}}\le  \frac{-\sqrt{(2n^2-n)^2}}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}} $$
with
$$\frac{1-2n^2}{\sqrt{4n^4}}=-1+\frac1{2n^2}\to -1+0=0$$
and
$$\frac{-\sqrt{(2n^2-n)^2}}{\sqrt{4n^4+2n^3}} =-\sqrt{1-\frac{4n^3-n^2}{4n^4+2n^3}} \to -\sqrt{1-0}=-1$$

Are you sure about the first inequalities, because $\sqrt{4n^2} \leq \sqrt{4n^2+2n^3}$ so the fraction should be greater since the denominator is smaller o am I missing something?

the value is negative $(-5<-4)$, to avoid confusion we can multiply by $-1$ and reverse all of course!

I miss that detail, crystal clear!
